# How do I get zend to recognize the paths to Propel ORM

Tags: database, zend-framework, orm, pdo, propel

I am trying to get Propel to work in my Zend app, it seems that I can get the Propel library to load (from library/propel) but when called I get the exception: 'No connection information in your runtime configuration file for datasource [default]' (when I try to make a connection: 'Propel::getConnection'). My Db is not even named 'default'. I have this in my bootstrap.php from another SO question/answer:

```
           require_once 'propel/Propel.php';
       Propel::setConfiguration($this->getOptions('propel/MyPropel-conf.php'));
       Propel::initialize();

       // so we can get the connection from the registry easily
       return Propel::getConnection();
```

I want the Propel configs (classmap conf as well) to be in the '/application/configs' (copies are there too right now), but I thought If I can get Propel to load from library/propel, then maybe moving my 'conf' files there, I may get them to load too. It seems that if I 'force' the config, by manually loading the params, or if I seem to get it in a temporary 'right' location (or use an absolute path), the exception I then get is this:
'Unable to open PDO connection [wrapped: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost'
As if Propel is not paying any attention to my configs.
My config looks like this; converted from the xml:

```
    $conf = array (
  'datasources' => 
  array (
    'unmActTestDB' => 
    array (
      'adapter' => 'mysql',
      'connection' => 
      array (
        'dsn' => 'mysql://root:PASSWORD@localhost/unmActTestDB',
      ),
    ),
    'default' => 'unmActTestDB',
  ),
  'log' => 
  array (
    'ident' => 'propel-act',
    'level' => '7',
  ),
  'generator_version' => '1.5.6',
);
$conf['classmap'] = include(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classmap-unmActTestDB-conf.php');
return $conf;
```

If it helps, I still have the Zend PDO DB adapter loading in the application.ini file too, would that cause a clash?. Is there a standard way to get Propel to work with Zend? Or can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

I have been to several posts here on SO, and a couple popular posts like this one [The Adventures Of Merging Propel With Zend Framework](http://www.brandonsavage.net/the-adventures-of-merging-propel-with-zend-framework/) and this one at Zend's dev zone [Integrating Propel with the Zend Framework](http://devzone.zend.com/article/184), among others including the Propel Docs. They have been helpful, but I am really struggling with this. Thanks in advance! My current Zend Directory structure looks like this (w/ the two propel confs also in the library/propel folder:

[image: Directory Structure]

Comment: I've worked out the path issues and the connection issue was due to my  ommitance of <user> & <password> in my runtime conf xml file.

Comment: You should post that as an answer. Nothing wrong with answering your own question

Comment: @PHil Brown Your right, and sorry...I'll get right to it! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I ended up doing is this:

I got a good grip on how to generate my models from a 'reverse' using Propel. It created (as before) a 'schema.xml' file for me to build my models with.

Also my 'runtime.xml' file was incorrect for my needs, after the build I was not connecting to the right database because of my omission of a few tags, overall it is quite simple though:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
 <log>
  <ident>unmActTestDB</ident>
  <level>7</level>
 </log>
 <propel>
  <datasources default="unmActTestDB">  
   <datasource id="unmActTestDB">
    <adapter>mysql</adapter>    
    <connection>
    <dsn>mysql:host=localhost;dbname=unmActTestDB</dsn>
    <user>zend</user>
    <password>PASSWORD</password>
    <database>unmActTestDB</database>
    </connection>    
   </datasource>   
  </datasources> 
 </propel>
</config>
```

The 'dsn' tag has to be in the format above with the addition of the 'user', 'password', and the 'database' tags. This fixed my issue with the database connection errors. As quoted above (and here) the exception thrown was:  'No connection information in your runtime configuration file for datasource [default]'

As far as the loading of my models goes, I ended up putting them in my 'library' folder, I already have that folder autoloading in my app, plus it seemed like a good place form them.

here is an image of my 'updated' directory structure:[image: My directory structure w/ Propel models]

Note the addition of the 'unmActTestDB' folder in my directory, this is my ORM models.
Another thing to note is that I put my generated 'conf' files into my 'application/configs' folder. These are correct now, after the correction of the runtime.xml file and a 'rebuild'.

As a side note, I had to edit my 'schema.xml' file by hand (several times :) )...The original database used plural names for the tables, so I edited all the 'phpname' declarations (attributes actually, on the  declaration tag) to be singular so I wouldn't access an object called 'Users'...instead I can now access a 'User' object. I kept the table names the same (tables are plural, and I won't have any issues importing the existing data, etc.) This was suggested by an answer to another one of my questions, see here [How to get related object Propel ORM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5446320/how-to-get-related-object-propel-orm).

The other big edit I made was to add primary key declarations (again,  attributes) for the many SQL views in the DB, also I added a 'readonly' and a 'noSQL' attributes to the  declarations, this way I will have access (through the Propel models) to my views.

And, just to be thorough, and for those who are interested here is the addition to my  'bootstrap.php' file that does my 'Propel Init' for me...

```
protected function _initPropel()
        {
            $this->_logger->info('Bootstrap ' . __METHOD__);

            require '../library/propel/Propel.php';
            Propel::init(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/unmActTestDB-conf.php');
            Propel::initialize();

            return Propel::getConnection();
        }
```

Another NOTE: the '$this->_logger->info('Bootstrap ' . **METHOD**);' calls my 'logging' method that just tells 'firePHP' that this method has loaded. The /configs/unmActTestDB-conf.php' calls the second 'conf' file that Propel generates... and here is the 'corrected' version of that file (the unmActTestDB.conf file that is), Note the changes in the 'connection' array.

```
<?php
// This file generated by Propel 1.5.6 convert-conf target
// from XML runtime conf file runtime-conf.xml
$conf = array (
  'datasources' => 
  array (
    'unmActTestDB' => 
    array (
      'adapter' => 'mysql',
      'connection' => 
      array (     
        'dsn' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=unmActTestDB',
        'user' => 'zend',
        'password' => 'PASSWORD', 
        'database' => 'unmActTestDB', 
      ),
    ),
    'default' => 'unmActTestDB',
  ),
  'log' => 
  array (
    'ident' => 'unmActTestDB',
    'level' => '7',
  ),
  'generator_version' => '1.5.6',
);
$conf['classmap'] = include(dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'classmap-unmActTestDB-conf.php');
return $conf;
```

I am off and running now! This was a great way to go, otherwise I was looking and writing sooo many mapping classes for my app. Propel (currently) generates over 300 models for this application! Plus the base classes, it would take me forever...